# Using bcrypt in a Glassfish 3.0 security realm

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, bcrypt, jdbcrealm

I'm currently in the process of changing the password handling in a web application from unsalted MD5 to bcrypt. It's a standard JSF application, running on Glassfish 3.0.1.
Using jBCrypt made creating and storing the hashes pretty easy. But now I don't know how to use bcrypt in the actual authentication when the user logs in. Since it's JSF, the login is being triggered using the HttpServletRequest#login method and the rest is being handled by the Java EE stack and Glassfish.

Simply setting the security realms digest algorithm to "none" and then hashing the password before passing it the login method wouldn't work, because I don't have the generated salt jBCrypt originally used when creating the hash.
I've also though about providing a custom security realm implementation, but that seems a lot work for such a small change.

Is there a simpler solution? Or has someone already implemented similar security realm?

Comment: Is this something you're still interested in? I've built a little custom realm for my current project. If you are let me know and I'll clean it up and put it on github with some documentation.

Comment: @ChadWilson, I'd be interested in seeing what you did for this.

Comment: Quick FYI: In the end I set digest algorithm in Glassfish to "none" and implemented hashing in the application. Unfortunately I've not been able to use bcrypt (not enough time for the necessary changes). Instead the application now uses a slow hashing algorithm with multiple iterations, starting with a fixed salt and then using the last hash as the salt on all subsequent iterations. Not the best solution, but still reasonably secure.

Answer (score 0):

implementing a login module should be enough, and delegating the authentication to underlying realm.